# Search/filter based on a menu list with AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, search, filtering, alpine.js

I'm fairly new to Alpine.js and looking to create a simple search/filter input to a list of items.

I've seen some [examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwFejyumY2Y) using `<template>`, but im not interested in that particular technique.

The list of items already exist on page, so it's a simple goal of hidding and un-hidding items based on a 'tag' array.

1. I need to get all the items in the list (along with submenus). (Hence using `x-ref` on the `<li>` and `<ul>`
2. Filter the array, based on the search input. (Stuck)
3. Hide remaining lists that !== search input. (Stuck)

I've got an simple example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/aaron-stez/pen/mdLNWJO?editors=1010)

I'm not sure the best way to bind the list items to `x-data`, and then I presume using a `.filter( $ref.startsWith(.this.search))` to filter the items.

‍♂️

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `x-ref` you need to use `$el` magic property that refers to the current DOM element: just pass it to a `show_item($el)` method that returns `true` if the `textContent` property of the element contains the search string.

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" x-data="{
  search: '',
  show_item(el) {
    return this.search === '' || el.textContent.includes(this.search)
  }
}">

  <input class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Filter: A B C D" x-model="search">

  <div>
    <p>Search Input: <span x-text="search"></span></p>
  </div>

  <p><b>Menu:</b></p>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item A</li>
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item B</li>
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">
      Dropdown C
      <ul>
        <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item C:A</li>
        <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item C:B</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item D</li>
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item E</li>
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item F</li>
    <li x-show="show_item($el)">
      Dropdown G
      <ul>
        <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item G:A</li>
        <li x-show="show_item($el)">Item G:B</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this worked perfectly. Thank you for the help! I have accepted the answer as it's correct for the question I asked, however if I'm using x-show to show/hide the child dropdowns in the menu, (closed on page load), can the dropdown inherit the show/hide of the search function. I've updated my codepen to show you what I mean. ... I know that x-data is inherited by child/nested x-data components. So on the `<ul>` could i do x-show="isOpen || show_item($el)" to show the hidden ul elements if a search has been initiated ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, you can put any regular JS code inside an Alpine.js directive. I guess you also want to modify the `x-show` attribute of the children `<li>` elements as well if you want to show them when `isOpen` is `true` on their `<ul>` parent element.

Comment: I tried adding `x-show="isOpen || show_item($el)"` to the ul, but it doesn't seem to want to play ball. It seems to break the alpine on the dropdown menu. https://codepen.io/aaron-stez/pen/mdLNWJO?editors=1010

Comment: Solved it. `x-show="isOpen || search != ''"` Thanks for your help pal! :)